# tensorflow learnable weight coeffecient with keras API

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I would like to make a loss function of the following form:

L = l1(x) + (1/w1)*l2(x) + (1/w2)*l3(x) + ln(1+(w1*w1 + w2*w2)

where w1 and w2 are learn-able.  Usually, these weight coefs are fixed.  I can create a tf model where these variables are trainable, but I am unsure how to do this with the keras API.

How does one specify this using the tf.keras api and how can I examine their values while training?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a custom layer containing the weights w1 & w2.

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from keras import backend as K

class CustomLayer(layers.Layer):

  def __init__(self):
    super(CustomLayer, self).__init__()

  def build(self, input_shape):
    self.w1 = self.add_weight(shape=(1,),
                             initializer='ones',
                             trainable=True)

    self.w2 = self.add_weight(shape=(1,),
                             initializer='ones',
                             trainable=True)

  def call(self, inputs):
    y_true = inputs[:,:1]
    y_pred = inputs[:,1:]
    loss = K.sum((y_pred - y_true) ** 2. + self.w1 + self.w2, -1) #loss calculation
    self.add_loss(loss, inputs=inputs) # add the loss
    return  K.square(inputs) # not used


model = Sequential()
model.add(layers.Input(shape=(2,)))
model.add(CustomLayer())
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss=None) #no loss updation here
X = np.random.randn(10, 2)
model.fit(X, epochs=2)
```

Output:

```
10/10 [==============================] - 0s 6ms/sample - loss: 3.6391
Epoch 2/2
10/10 [==============================] - 0s 103us/sample - loss: 3.6371
```

Complete example available here: https://github.com/yaringal/multi-task-learning-example

https://www.tensorflow.org/beta/guide/keras/custom_layers_and_models#layers_encapsulate_a_state_weights_and_some_computation

Comment: This doesnt quite answer my question. You made a custom layer but I need to make a custom loss with trainable coeffecients.

Comment: This model can be used to learn the coefficients given the loss & x. Can you please elaborate the use case where you need learnable weights in the loss?

Comment: I would like my loss function to be L = l1(x) + (1/w1)*l2(x) + (1/w2)*l3(x) + ln(1+(w1*w1 + w2*w2) where w1 and w2 are learnable weights.  In the code you specified, you havent provided any loss function to the network (you have no model.compile() function call.  Please add that.

Comment: I updated the answer. Also, provided link to complete github example.

Comment: Is there a way to still have a primary loss which is in the compile() function?

Comment: How would you implement this so that the functional API can be used instead of the sequential like you show in your example.  The example code you cite is 2 years old with such an example is 2 years old.

Comment: What is the type and size of X?

Comment: X is a numpy array in this case. Sorry, missed the declaration of X. I updated the answer. I just pass random values for y_true & y_pred. But in the real case, it could be the output of a model as in the example notebook I linked to. The example notebook uses the functional API approach.

Comment: How does tf tally up the losses if use loss_weights in .compile() and sample weights in .train_on_batch()?

Comment: How can someone use the approach you provided in the Functional API style?